# crash on android app launch

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have a lot of bugs since the update of visual studio 2017 yesterday.
The most important is that when I try to emulate my app to android emulator for visual studio, the build and deployment work well but when the app is lauched, it crashes less than one second later.
After the deployment, I can see the following message in the output:

```
The android App is debugging
referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47302 1
Connexion to logcat impossible. GetProcessId returned : 0
```

I checked the logcat manually but there is no error in it.
In addition, when I try to launch the app from the emulator directly, it still crashes..
Do somebody has the same problem? or a solution?

Comment: Open Task Manager and see if adb.exe is present in the list of Processes. If not, try to run it manually by going to this path: your_sdk>platform-tools> run adb.exe

Comment: it is already launched

Comment: I had same problem couple days ago, I couldn't launch my app and showed the same message. What I did is restart my adb and disabled 'Fast deployment' in project settings.

Comment: Uncheck fast deployment solved the problem! Thank s a lot

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy coding!